# Ranger file manager becomes unresponsive on using some applications

Tags: ranger

Suppose I open a text file using `Emacs` or a picture using `Gimp` then the `Ranger` file manager becomes unresponsive till you close this application.

However if I open the same text file say using `Gedit` or the picture using `Eye of Gnome`, then the `Ranger` file manager session is still active and I can use it to move around the folders, browse files and do the usual operations.

Why is this happening?

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: you can use `strace` to have a look at what `Ranger` is doing. Possibly it's blocked waiting for something. Maybe you can find out what that something is by using `strace` on the `Ranger` process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` which will run the command asynchronously, so ranger will still be usable while you have the application open.

For example, in your `rifle.conf` use the following line:

```
mime ^text,  label editor = emacs & -- "$@"
```

instead of

```
mime ^text,  label editor = emacs -- "$@"
```

Similarly suppose you want to open an image with `gimp` then you can press `r` in `ranger` to open a list of available applications. The list might look like:

```
0 | eog -- "$@"
1 | feh -- "$@"
2 | eom -- "$@"
3 | gimp -- "$@"
:open_with
```

Then use `3 &` instead of `3` to open the image in `gimp` while keeping ranger usable.

Sometime `ranger` may not be configured to recognize the correct application (for example `mathematica`). You can still choose that application by typing the name of the application at the prompt `:open_with`. However to keep the ranger still responsive use the flag `f` as in:

```
:open_with mathematica f
```

(the above method to use a flag`f` is from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356732/ranger-open-with-without-suspending))