# Ranger, open file freeze the terminal

Tags: terminal, ranger

I set Viewnior for open image files, but when I open any image file (jpg or png) ranger stays frozen or something similar, and I only can return to ranger when I close the app that opened the file. Therefore, I can't open other files, only one.

My rifle.conf :

```
ext png = viewnior "$@"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ranger - open\_with without suspending](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356732/ranger-open-with-without-suspending)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be, based on an [sample rifle.conf file](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rifle.conf) I found, that you'd need the `f` flag to ask Ranger to `Fork the program, make it run in the background`:

```
ext png, flag f = viewnior "$@"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issu by adding & at the end.

```
ext png, flag f = viewnior "$@" &
```

The "&" force the program to be run in th backgournd.

Comment: Are you sure you need both `flag f` _and_ the `&`? The `f`` flag is described as running the application in the background

Comment: the flag f doesn't worked for me, perhaps it was some specifick issue, after putting & on the end everything work as a charm.